# Laravel: Best practice for inline PHP in a blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So I have the following blade file:

`confirmEmail.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
{{ trans('tc.signUpConfirmTitle')}}
@endsection





@section('body')


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">

      <?php
      echo $_GET['emailToken'];
      $emailToken = isset($_GET['emailToken']) ? $_GET['emailToken'] : "";
      $email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : "";

      //database lookup:
      $user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();   //this fails...

      if($user->emailToken == $emailToken){
        echo "OK!";
      }
      ?>




      <br><br><br><br><br><br>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

As you can see, I have some raw PHP between `<?php ?>` tags. The problem is that `User::where(...)` is failing ("FatalErrorException" - Class 'User' not found).

I guess this is because I need to do some Laravel import? But is doing this lightweight?

Can I ask what the best practice would be in this my case? I'm still very new to Laravel so bear with me. Is using raw PHP like this defeating the whole purpose?

I've been using Blade templates for spitting out simple variables and parameters fine up until now. But I want to do something a little more complicated now and I'm having trouble.

Comment: Hi folks, I think I figured it out... If I use `\App\User::where('email','=',$email)->first()` it works fine...

Comment: why are you executing all this logic in your blade file ?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with putting php on a template but  you're using $_GET directly.. not laravel way. and this is too much syntax in a view :(

Comment: Hi @KhanShahrukh Can you please comment some more. I guess I should pass a simple variable in from my controller class, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is using raw PHP like this defeating the whole purpose?
Exactly ! MVC are made so that there will be different layers of different type of jobs "Model,View and Controller" here in your case you are combining the job of controller into a view and hence diminishing the role of controller.

The following code in your controller will do what you are trying to do. Lets say you have a function named confirmation which is responsible for all the validation and returning the response accordingly.

```
public function confirmation(Request $request)
{
   $status = 'Failure';
   $emailToken = $request->emailToken;
   $email = $request->email;
   if(isset($email))
     {
       $user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
        //I do not know why this fails on your side check if you have that email in your database
       if($user->emailToken == $emailToken)
        {
          $status = 'Success';
        }
     }
          return view('confirmEmail')->with('message', $status);
}
```

You should not add confirmation key into users table however its your db table you can insert anything anywhere but my suggestion is you should create a separate table for that.

Comment: Hello. Very useful comments. I've learnt about MVC and still getting used to Laravel and trying to force myself to relearn the way I'm used to doing things. I guess I'm getting old...

Comment: did you watch videos of jeffrey way ? if not search laracasts on google

Comment: hey @Eamorr sorry for irrelevant comment but hows your MVC learning going ?